# How to make gravitational lens visualizing program?

Tags: general-relativity

I'm not living in the English-using country, so please understand my bad grammar.
I want to make a program which is visualize gravitational lens.
I want program give me an image, with metric tensor and null-geodesic equation which I entered. 
Trace the route of the light to use numerical solving of null-geodesic equation is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is actually very complicated.  However, just in case you are capable of doing the maths and the programming, there is a program which does some of what you are describing [here](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/kerr.html).

It computes a ray-traced image around a Kerr black hole, not a general curved spacetime, but it will give you some technical pointers, and also give you an idea whether you really want to proceed with this!

[Here](http://gyoto.obspm.fr/) is another one that I just remembered.

Answer (score 1):

You will find several real-time online compact implementations on shadertoy, here : https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=black+hole (you can also easily modify them, including uncommenting features). Illustrating:

- lens effect on the background
- lens effect on the accretion disc

Take care, not all are physical (it's pretty easy to see, anyway :-) ), and some of the physical simulations have shortcuts (e.g. no explicit dl, embeded in the various constants).

Comment: Thank you, too. so that's shadertoy function is just looks-like black hole, or based on real science calculation?

Comment: most are based on real simulation of light bending, splitting in  2 cases: full 3D (good for distortion of the disc), or close form for background distortion.

Comment: I can't find any evidence of physics calculations on that site, it looks like general 3D effects site.  Can you provide a mathematical link to what we are actually looking at?

Comment: this site just host programms of very various kind. Look the sources of the one I pointed to see numerical simulation of bended rays.

Comment: The following ones have some kind of gravitational lensing, IINM: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ws2GWD, https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlBXzd,  https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mds3DM. I have no idea which if any are physically accurate.